# Stuck on Objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

**Instructions**

Complete the `canIGet` function. This function should:

- Take two arguments:
- `item`: represents what the user wants to buy
- `money`: represents how many dollars a user has
- return `true` if a user can afford a given item according to the price chart below, and false otherwise:

  - 'MacBook Air' - $999
  - MacBook Pro' - $1299
  - 'Mac Pro' - $2499
  - 'Apple Sticker' - $1
- Return `false` if the `item` is not in the above list of Apple products

  > Do this with 0 'if' conditions! (Hint: Place the above price table in an object).

```
canIGet('MacBook Air', 100) // returns false
canIGet('MacBook Air', 1000) // returns true
```

---

**My Code**

```
canIGet = function(item, money) {
    var macItems = {
        "MacBook Air": 999,
        "MacBook Pro": 1299,
        "Mac Pro": 2499,
        "Apple Sticker": 1
    }


    return macItems.item >= money;
};
```

This passes through the JavaScript Console. However when I am testing it through the terminal (mocha tests) it would fail and have the following results:

**Terminal Results**

```
canIGet

✓ should be defined
1) returns the correct results for MacBook Air
2) returns the correct results for MacBook Pro
3) returns the correct results for Mac Pro
4) returns correct results for Apple Sticker
✓ returns false for non-Apple products
```

Comment: You can only get it if money>= price.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use bracket notation since you're passing a string as your property referrer:

```
return macItems[item] <= money;
```

also make sure to use `<=` if you want to test for affordability:

```
function canIGet(item, money) {
    return {
        "MacBook Air": 999,
        "MacBook Pro": 1299,
        "Mac Pro": 2499,
        "Apple Sticker": 1
    }[item] <= money;
}

console.log( canIGet("MacBook Air", 998) ); // false
```

Comment: Thanks for your help Roko it passed!

Answer (score 0):

If you are having trouble solving any kind of problem always debug it. Simple way to do it is by using console.log()

The issues is that macItems.item does not work and you need to use macItems[item] notation

Return statement is also have flipped logic in there. macItems.item should have lower value than money that is passed in to return true i.e Air cost 999 and I have 1000 money, that would be equal to 999 >= 1000,and  that would return false. It should be flipped to return macItems[item] <= money

Function with debug info

```
canIGet = function(item, money) {
console.log(item)
console.log(money)
var macItems = {
        "MacBook Air": 999,
        "MacBook Pro": 1299,
        "Mac Pro": 2499,
        "Apple Sticker": 1
    }

    console.log(macItems[item])
    return macItems[item] <= money;
};
```

Comment: Awesome explanation, totally understood it now. Thanks for your help!